# Bootstrap Bootsnipp snippet won't render correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, code-snippets

I'm trying to use a Bootsnipp snippet in my page.
Namely, [collapsible-tree-menu-with-accordion](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/collapsible-tree-menu-with-accordion).
However the entire thing is being rendered in a 'flat' way. The collapse/expand mechanism is working fine, but the list items are not indented, nor are they surrounded with a box.

I imagine this is a CSS issue, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the HTML (generated from django templates), with the snippet pasted as-is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title></title>

    <link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hasadna: Community</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">admin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

    <ol class="breadcrumb">

<li><a href="/users/">Users</a></li>
<li class="active">Lucid</li>

    </ol>


<div class="well">
    <center>
        <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8b1d41ccb353509f6c864b1faddf3202?d=blank?s=140" name="aboutme" width="140" height="140" border="0" class="img-circle"></a>
        <h3 class="media-heading">Lucid</h3>
        <h3 class="media-heading"><small>עמרי דור | Omri Dor</small></h3>
        <span><strong>Skills: </strong></span>
        <span class="label label-warning">Baking Cookies</span>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <p class="text-left"><strong>Email: </strong><br>
        <a href="mailto:a@b.c"> a@b.c</a></p>
    <hr>
    <center>
        <p class="text-left"><strong>Bio: </strong><br>
            Hi guys.
</p>
    </center>


    <hr>
    <p class="text-left"><strong>Code Contributions: </strong></p>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Total Commits:</strong> 7</li>            
    </ul>


    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="accordion">
                    <!-- Áreas -->
                    <div class="accordion-group">
                        <!-- Área -->
                        <div class="accordion-heading area">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href=
                            "#area1">Área #1</a>

                            <div class="dropdown edit">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle icon-pencil" data-toggle=
                                "dropdown" href="#" style="font-style: italic"></a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <!-- Adicionar equipamento -->

                                    <li>
                                        <a href="../equipamento/add.php"><i class=
                                        "icon-plus"></i> Adicionar equipamento</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="divider"></li><!-- Editar área -->

                                    <li>
                                        <a href="../area/edit.php"><i class=
                                        "icon-pencil"></i> Editar área</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="divider"></li><!-- Remover área -->

                                    <li>
                                        <a class="danger" href="#remove"><i class=
                                        "icon-remove"></i> Remover área</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /Área -->

                        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="area1">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                                <div class="accordion" id="equipamento1">
                                    <!-- Equipamentos -->

                                    <div class="accordion-group">
                                        <div class="accordion-heading equipamento">
                                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent=
                                            "#equipamento1-1" data-toggle="collapse" href=
                                            "#ponto1-1">Equipamento #1-1</a>

                                            <div class="dropdown edit">
                                                <a class="dropdown-toggle icon-pencil"
                                                data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style=
                                                "font-style: italic"></a>

                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <!-- Adicionar ponto -->

                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href=
                                                        "../ponto/add.php"><i class="icon-plus">
                                                        </i> Adicionar ponto</a>
                                                    </li>

                                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                                    <!-- Editar equipamento -->

                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href=
                                                        "../equipamento/edit.php"><i class=
                                                        "icon-pencil"></i> Editar
                                                        equipamento</a>
                                                    </li>

                                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                                    <!-- Remover equipamento -->

                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="danger" href=
                                                        "#remove"><i class=
                                                        "icon-remove"></i> Remover
                                                        equipamento</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- Pontos -->

                                        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="ponto1-1">
                                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                                                <div class="accordion" id="servico1">
                                                    <div class="accordion-group">
                                                        <div class=
                                                        "accordion-heading ponto">
                                                            <a class="accordion-toggle"
                                                            data-parent="#servico1-1-1"
                                                            data-toggle="collapse" href=
                                                            "#servico1-1-1">Ponto
                                                            #1-1-1</a>

                                                            <div class="dropdown edit">
                                                                <a class=
                                                                "dropdown-toggle icon-pencil"
                                                                data-toggle="dropdown"
                                                                href="#" style=
                                                                "font-style: italic"></a>

                                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                                    <!-- Adicionar servico -->

                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <a href=
                                                                        "../servico/add.php">
                                                                        <i class=
                                                                        "icon-plus"></i>
                                                                        Adicionar
                                                                        servico</a>
                                                                    </li>

                                                                    <li class="divider">
                                                                    </li><!-- Editar ponto -->

                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <a href=
                                                                        "../ponto/edit.php">
                                                                        <i class=
                                                                        "icon-pencil"></i>
                                                                        Editar ponto</a>
                                                                    </li>

                                                                    <li class="divider">
                                                                    </li><!-- Remover ponto -->

                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <a class="danger"
                                                                        href=
                                                                        "#remove"><i class=
                                                                        "icon-remove"></i>
                                                                        Remover ponto</a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div><!-- Serviços -->

                                                        <div class=
                                                        "accordion-body collapse" id=
                                                        "servico1-1-1">
                                                            <div class="accordion-inner">
                                                                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <a href=
                                                                        "#"><i class=
                                                                        "icon-chevron-right">
                                                                        </i> Serviço
                                                                        #1-1-1-1</a>
                                                                    </li>

                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <a href=
                                                                        "#"><i class=
                                                                        "icon-chevron-right">
                                                                        </i> Serviço
                                                                        #1-1-1-2</a>
                                                                    </li>

                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <a href=
                                                                        "#"><i class=
                                                                        "icon-chevron-right">
                                                                        </i> Serviço
                                                                        #1-1-1-3</a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div><!-- /Serviços -->
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- /Pontos -->
                                    </div><!-- /Equipamentos -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /accordion -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



</div>





    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p></p>
    </footer>
</div>


<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the additional CSS file, '/static/css/style.css', containing the CSS snippet that's supposed to go along with the HTML snippet:

```
body {
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.menu .accordion-heading {  position: relative; }
.menu .accordion-heading .edit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 30px;
}
.menu .area { border-left: 4px solid #f38787; }
.menu .equipamento { border-left: 4px solid #65c465; }
.menu .ponto { border-left: 4px solid #98b3fa; }
.menu .collapse.in { overflow: visible; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The boxes and indentation are coming from styles applied to `.accordion-inner` via bootstrap.min.css (in the example you linked). Sure you have that CSS file loaded?

Comment: I have tried to replicate issue but couldn't. I have used bootstrap 2.3.2 and everything works fine. Check this http://jsbin.com/bukin/1/.  Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys! It was indeed a version problem as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had two problems:

1. I was using Bootstrap v3.1.0, which was incompatible with this snippet.
2. Even after switching to v2.3.2, the files sat in the same exact (django served /static/) path, and my browser kept using the cached version (3.1.0).

About (1):
Unfortunately if I go back to 2.3.2 then my navbar is no longer rendered correctly. I would really like to migrate the snippet to Bootstrap 3.1.0, but my CSS is far too poor for  me to be able to do it.

About (2):
A quick workaround was to indicate the version number somewhere in the path (i.e. boostrap/2.3.2/css/...).

A cleaner solution is django-cachebuster, which adds a meaningless get parameter for your static resources (i.e. /static/my.css?v=9393939). This parameter can be set to be the file's last modification date, so that ought to do it.

Thanks for your help guys!